# Using mpf_set_ui on a float array stops output (GMP c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, gmp

For a school project I have to do a couple of calculations involving large numbers, that's why I have chosen to use GMP. After encountering strange bugs in my main program I started experimenting in another one. The following code shows what's going wrong:

```
mpf_set_default_prec(512);
mpf_t t[5];
mpf_init(t[5]);
cout << "This does appear." << endl;
mpf_set_ui(t[4],9);
cout << mpf_get_d(t[4]) << endl;
cout << "This does not, neither is the number 9 printed." << endl;
mpf_clear(t[5]);
```

So all the output stops after mpf_set_ui. If I try this without an array, so t[5] and t[4] become t, everything works as expected. What am I doing wrong? Are arrays actually allowed in GMP?

Comment: `mpf_init(t[5]);` This accesses the array outside of the valid bounds (`0-4`)!

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! (edit: for clarity, one must change mpf_init(t[5]); into mpf_init(t[4]);)

Comment: ... and don't forget the other occurrences of `t[5]`. You probably will need a (`for()`) loop to initialize and handle all of the array elements correctly.

Comment: Since the question is tagged [c++], I would recommend the C++ wrapper: https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html . And for bigfloats, in new projects, it is better to use mpfr than gmp, which concentrates on integers and rationals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably change your code as follows

```
mpf_t t[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    mpf_init(t[i]);
}

mpf_set_ui(t[4],9);
cout << mpf_get_d(t[4]) << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    mpf_clear(t[i]);
}
```